# Is there a dynamic pruning in geth --fast?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, state-trie-pruning, fast-sync

Once i've downloaded the blockchain with geth --fast , is there a dynamic pruning on the up-comings blocks, or will I archive all the blocks from where I stand?

Comment: Note: As of November 2017 the `--fast` command-line option is now deprecated. Instead there is now `--syncmode "fast"`, `--syncmode "full"` and `--syncmode "light"`. This is briefly documented here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options and explained here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11297/what-is-geths-light-sync-and-why-is-it-so-fast/18817

Comment: @Dai why is the parameter between "" ? bash would filter those away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple answer no. --fast download a pruned version of the state tries, but it behaves like archive after. So if you want spare disk, remove your blockchain with geth removedb and do a --fast again.

Comment: I thought that in some way, there was a reference count which would end some tx in a "death row"; but it's not clear... I have a reference from Vitalik Butterin here : https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/06/26/state-tree-pruning/

Comment: What is you Source?