# Why downloading the Blockchain with GETH --fast is still very slow

Tags: blockchain, ethereumj, windows

My attempt to install Mist on my PC since May 16, 2017 failed miserably many times. Fact is, I am able to install the app no problem. The problem I have is that it just takes forever to download the whole BlockChain. Hence, rending my installation useless. I've done a lot of reading about how to speed up the process and found the commonly suggested solution as follow:

geth --fast --cache=2048 --jitvm and many variants.
All variants have been tried with not much efficiency increase.

Also, on my 64bits 6Gigs RAM Intel i5 2.5GHz decent PC I did the following:

```
*Uninstall the whole Ethereum Mist program from Windows 7   
*Deleted all folders created on prior installation attempts,   
   including all ethereum related folders in my AppData folder.   
*re-installed a fresh version of the newest Mist Mist-win64-0-8-10.zip   
*Once installed I stopped the blockchain sync process   
*opened a console windows    
*called 

GETH removedb   
GETH --fast --cache=2048     also tried  GETH --fast --cache=2048 --jitvm
```

The process started correctly.
That process is suppose to start downloading the whole blockchain without any calculations or details. Should be much faster.
I waited 5 days until I decided to stop the attempt, for at every time extrapolation calculation I found that the termination date was pushed further and further ahead to some 20 days in the future.

This is just insane. There's got to be something I am doing wrong.

Furthermore, when stopped, the GETH --fast --cache=2048 will not continue as in the first attempt.
The console will mention and error message containing  "fast mode disable" ??

I realize that this subject has been addressed many times here but none have been recent. I am just hoping to find an up-to-date solution since all previous attempts have failed.

Does anyone have any suggestion as to how one can install the Ethereum blockchain faster than a whole month of computer saturation ? !

*Note for similar previous questions: In my view this question is different from many of the other questions addressing the slow speed for syncing the Ethereum wallet by the fact that the previous answers are not relatively recent and the Ethereum wallet as taken a huge size increase since a year (2016 to 2017). Clearly, this issue is becoming a major one. Taking over one month to get a synced blockchain is way out of sense. My question is an attempt to seek a recent answer to an old question that clearly need a fresher approach.

Answer (score 4):

Try `geth --light`

> Light Sync: Gets only the current state. To verify elements, needs to
>   ask to full (archive) nodes for the corresponding tree leave.

You may take a look at [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11297/what-is-geths-light-sync-and-why-is-it-so-fast)

Comment: Can a light node get a transaction by hash? I'm particularly interested in these commands: `personal_newAccount`, `eth_getTransactionByHash`, `eth_getBlockByNumber`, `eth_blockNumber`, `eth_getBlockByNumber`, `personal_unlockAccount`, and `eth_getBalance`

Answer (score 3):

I'm using geth VERSION: 1.6.5-stable-cf87713d

in the Geth --help you can read

```
DEPRECATED OPTIONS:
  --fast   Enable fast syncing through state downloads
  --light  Enable light client mode
```

I'm using

```
--syncmode "fast"     Blockchain sync mode ("fast", "full", or "light")
```

I hope it's help.