# "being full node" vs."being sync" : Are they the same?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, parity, synchronization, nodes

When we try to be `sync` using `Parity` or `geth`, Does it mean that we are trying to be a `full node` ?

And is it correct to say that:

being `sync` = being a `full node` = keeping the **entire** blockchain ?

Comment: possible dup, check https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1161/20276

Comment: @nyusternie It may be similar but not the same question. My question is `being sync` means `being full node` ? Or they are two different terms ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ethereum and its clients knows a few modes of syncing.

There is "full", "light" and "fast" according to [the geth docs](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options).

Only with "full" you actually download and validate everything.

[This post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11297/what-is-geths-light-sync-and-why-is-it-so-fast) explains it.

Basically the faster the node spins up, the less validation is done to retrieve state.

Parity has for itself a few implementations of operation.

[Their docs can be found here](https://wiki.parity.io/Configuring-Parity-Ethereum)

Parity is a **light** client which means by default it does not serve as a full node.

This means

`parity` kinda corresponds to `geth --light`.

And both of those mean that state is being reconstructed by validating less deep (more or less).

`parity --warp` is similar to `geth --fast` in performance, altough for Parity this means the client looks for data from another full node and simply trusts it while Geth will retrieve state by simply pulling hashes from blocks instead of the whole block. [It is being discussed here.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/what-is-geths-fast-sync-and-why-is-it-faster)

Starting Parity in "warp-mode" means the current state is read from some trusted snapshot:

https://wiki.parity.io/Getting-Synced.html

You can read more about warp [here!](https://wiki.parity.io/Warp-Sync-Snapshot-Format.html)

> Every 5,000 blocks, nodes will take a consensus-critical snapshot of that block’s state. Any node can fetch these snapshots over the network, enabling a fast sync.

This can all be a little confusing. One parameter in Parity says  **what** is validated while another decides **when** is being validated.

Then there is the `--mode` option which configures **when** Parity syncs. This decides **at which times the program on your PC operates and syncs**

```
--mode=[MODE]
    Set the operating mode. MODE can be one of: last - Uses
    the last-used mode, active if none; active - Parity
    continuously syncs the chain; passive - Parity syncs
    initially, then sleeps and wakes regularly to resync;
    dark - Parity syncs only when the JSON-RPC is active;
    offline - Parity doesn't sync. (default: last)
```

Comment: Thank you, This post : [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/11297/23024) is for `geth`. is there a similar approach for `Parity` ? Thanks

Comment: Btw, your link : `according to the docs` refers to this question url. could you please update it? Thanks

Comment: This is a rather complex topic, @sas . I updated to trie to summarize the parity part. But tbh I could go on for a few more pages to explain different modes of validation and synchronisation. If anything is unclear let me know. Also I fixed the link

Comment: I recently came across this article that goes into nice detail between the different modes of geth and parity [The Ethereum-blockchain size will not exceed 1TB anytime soon](https://dev.to/5chdn/the-ethereum-blockchain-size-will-not-exceed-1tb-anytime-soon-58a)