# Is it possible to download the Ethereum state trie and state database on their own?

Tags: go-ethereum, fast-sync, state-trie

I want to download a more or less recent version of the Ethereum state trie and state database, i.e. some version from within the last 1000 or so blocks. I know that I could set up a full node and let it sync completely, but that takes quite some time (even in `fast` mode) and requires an SSD in order for syncing to finish. Also, I am not interested in block headers at all, but only the state trie and state database.

Since Geth's `--syncmode fast` option "downloads the transaction receipts along the blocks, and pulls an entire recent state database" (see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/1889)), is there a way to only get that recent snapshot state database without downloading everything else?

Comment: You can have a light node, as explained [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11297/what-is-geths-light-sync-and-why-is-it-so-fast)

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work because a light node does not download state data. See my previous question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56981/does-geth-syncmode-light-download-the-state-trie).