# Speeding up Geth Synchronization

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

What would help speed up synchronization?

I'm not sure if it's a bandwidth issue or a CPU issue?

If I were to upgrade my processor would that help make it move faster or do I need to upgrade my download/up speed?

Answer (score 1):

Typically the bottleneck in synchronization is your I/O: your hard drive. I believe it's for example no longer possible to get fully synchronized with a HDD when using a full node - you have to use SSD. So it's not a bandwidth or a CPU issue.

Otherwise you can use the different (lighter) synchronization methods. Geth supports the following modes:

1) full: synchronize everything

2) fast: synchronize only essential parts of blocks

3) light (experimental): only latest state

You can read about their differences for example here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11300/31933