# What are the different space requirements for running an Ethereum node?

Tags: go-ethereum, full-node

I am trying to run an Ethereum testnet node in the Ropsten testnet and currently trying to figure out, what the requirements are for the disk space needed. While this is (obviously) different for the Ethereum mainnet (and the different testnets), there are also different approaches to run a node with different synchronization methods that will also affect disk usage.

e.g., geth allows different sync-modes, configuring whether the entire chain or only parts of it are to be synchronized (see [What is Geth's "light" sync, and why is it so fast?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11297/what-is-geths-light-sync-and-why-is-it-so-fast)).

Looking through the web, I found several pages with information about required for the main- and testnets, but I cant find any information about how the different sync-modes affect required disk-space. Is there a comprehensive (ideally dynamically updated) list of how much disk space all different networks need - for the individual sync-modes?

Links: Size mainnet https://etherscan.io/chart2/chaindatasizefast